# Disable div with click event

Tags: javascript, html, events, knockout.js

I want to disable my div with image and click event that event does not call. I try do it with KO:

```
<div title="Delete Series" class="deleteSeriesButton" data-bind="css: { disabled: true}" ></div>
```

but this does not work with div.

Can I do it without unbind click event?

Comment: turn it to `button` and then you can make it "disabled"

Comment: but i need div that it has image inside

Comment: button able contain images too!

Comment: i try it, but my button div is circle, and <button> has square border, it is not good for me

Comment: in css you can do what you want with it , look: http://jsfiddle.net/Zfub6/

Comment: or even this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zfub6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using KnockoutJS, then you have a view model.
And if you have a view model, you should be able to add an observable property that tells you whether the "delete series" button is enabled or disabled.

```
self.isDeleteEnabled = ko.computed(function() {
    // your code that tells whether the button is enabled or not
});
```

And let's say you in your view model the click action, like this:

```
self.clickAction = function() { 
    // do what you want to do 
}
```

Thne, you can make your "click" binding dependent on this observable, like this:

```
<div class="button" data-bind="click: isDeleteEnabled() ? clickAction : null">
```

If the isDeleteEnabled observable returns true, then the button is clickable, otherwise it's not.

I [made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XkvQG/) so you can see how it's done in a real example.

Answer (score 0):

you can block the div using the jQuery blockUI plugin.

[link to blockUI](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/&ei=o-e2UcytPIeGrQeCi4DYCg&usg=AFQjCNHR_3c-hRqH6iggzD-F2qNVEeqHpA&sig2=qYoqV9QL9_ATag7vAEGTjQ&bvm=bv.47534661,d.bmk)